# C# - How can I initilalize List<string[]> in the same line

Tags: c#, list, constructor

I want to initialize a list consisting of string arrays in the same line. How can I do that?

```
public List<string[]> list = new List<string>(/** What should I put here? */);
```

Comment: If you have static array of string, do you really require a list ? Will the list be updated later ?

Comment: @SteveB New elements are added later in the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
public List<string[]> list = new List<string[]> {
    new [] {"a","b","C"},
    new string[0],
    new [] {"d"}
};
```

That said, however:

- public fields are usually a bad idea
- list/collection members *with setters* are often a bad idea
- initializing and populating collections in a constructor is usually a bad idea

Comment: That's a very fast response. Thank you.

Why is initializing and populating collections in a constructor a bad idea?

Comment: @Developer505 usually the contents are for the *caller* to define, plus it can really mess up serialization - several serialization frameworks assume that collections will be empty, so if you deserialize an object, you could end up with the .ctor items *plus* the ones from the payload